# chrome extension css on localhost

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension.  The content has a stylesheet content.css.  When I run the extension on an external site, it applies the style sheet.  When I open a page on my "hello world" page on localhost, it applies the content.css styles initially but the styles go away if I refresh the page and I cannot get them back unless I refresh the extenstion.

Can't figure out why this is but I need to get this resolved.

Thanks,
Ken

Comment: Please post your manifest.json.